# Magento 2.4.6 How to remove or hide My Cart?

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart, mini-cart, magento2.4.6

I am using Magento 2.4.6, and using the multi-site function, One of the sites, I like to display as a catalog, does not need a shopping cart (My Cart). I know that hiding prices can hide the add to cart button on the product page, but I need to know how to delete or hide the My Cart in the navigation bar.

**Google Chrome：**
[image]

### **iphone mobile browser：**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Approach of this Scenario is to Create a Child theme and assign the that to specfic website

int the theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Is it possible if I don't want to delete or hide but to redirect the mini cart (My cart) to a new page?

Comment: for that you have to override vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml file in your theme and change functionality of aanchor tag